# How to fetch location or any updates in iOS after termination of app?

Tags: swift

I need to fetch location of other user even when the app has been killed by swiping up. I have tried push notification, SNS, FCM, push-kit everything. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to access data when the app has been killed, user needs to open it back first. You could send him a push notification that will open the app for example.

Comment: Thanks, but the app i have been working on is a clone of some another app and they have achieved this on both iOS and android platform. There must be a way?

Answer (score 0):

It is not an "explicitly" fetching location data. System will decide when your app will be launched.

To access data of location update event when user already killed app.
You need to prepare something:

- [Request permission Alway Authorization for app to access location data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/cllocationmanager/1620551-requestalwaysauthorization)
- [Enable Location update in Background Mode](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corelocation/getting_the_user_s_location/handling_location_events_in_the_background)
- Make a Singleton to handle for location change/authorization status. It wil be better when System wakes your app to run in Background to handle location event.